# How to extract information from an e-mail using php

Tags: php, email

I have an e-mail address that receives information about new advertisement campaigns for me to post on my sites. What I'm trying to do is extract information such as the campaign country and expiry date ...

It would be very helpful if you can point me in the right direction so I can continue my research.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that [IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Fluffeh is right: you want to implement (or use) a php based email client to open and read the messages in a mail account. Then you can process the content of the messages and react in any way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

@Zinger you can do this with [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) option

some email providers are allow to access email in directly on website.

see this link https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1737